# How do I remove the curly bracket in my output of dictionary and replace with output i prefer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, type-conversion, output

My output comes out in a curly bracket and dictionary style in a line but I would like it to format it differently. Ex: if input is `"hello i am"`

output:

```
am : 1
hello : 1 
i : 1
```

Here is my code:

```py
def word_count(q):

    i = dict()
 
    j = q.split()

    j.sort()
  
    for word in j:
        if word in i:
            i[word] += 1
        else:
            i[word] = 1

    return i

sent = input( ).lower()

x = word_count(q)
```

Comment: Does the order in your output matter, or could the lines be in any order?

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter`, this is a subclass of dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter

sent = input("Please provide the article: \n" ).lower()

counts = Counter(sorted(sent.split()))
```

To output as string:

```
print('\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k,v in counts.items()))
```

output:

```
am: 1
hello: 1
i: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

use f-string:

```
def word_count(sent):
    
    i = dict()
    j = sent.split()
    j.sort()
    
    for word in j:
        if word in i:
            i[word] += 1
        else:
            i[word] = 1
    for k in i:
        return f"{k}:{i[k]}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).